# Postback script issues

Tags: php

Ive been really struggling to see the issue with my postback script,

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
//$adscendIp = "xx.xx.xx.xx"; // ip for adsc

//if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != $adscendIp)
//{
//die("Access Denied!");
//}

$campid = $_GET['campid']; // ID number of the campaign credited
$sid = $_GET['sid']; // The SubID that was passed in the campaign link
$rate = $_GET['rate']; // Commission earned (Will be negative if status is revoked)
$status = $_GET['status']; // Status of the lead. 1 for payable, 2 for revoked
$name = $_GET['name']; // Name of the campaign
$ip = $_GET['ip']; // IP address of the user 
$cur = $_GET['cur'];
$sb1 = $_GET['sb1'];

if($status == "1")
{

    mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE users SET balance = '.$cur.' WHERE steamid = '.$sd1.'");

}
else
{
die("Revoked Lead!");
}
?>
```

Ive tried going to the link and putting the correct variables in the url and it seems to work, but when i try it on the offerwall its failing, is there anything you can see wrong with the script.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We can figure out it doesn't work (or you wouldn't post here). You need to explain how it fails. In any case, you are neither injecting data into SQL the right way (prepared statements) nor have you configured mysqli to report errors.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable for SQL Injection. User parameters binding and don't put user input directly to SQL query

Comment: I also suggest you check the manual section about [strings](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: I think you have a typo in your mysqli_query(). In there you have $sd1 but in your assignment you have $sb1 = $_GET['sb1'];

Answer (score 0):

your all variable i.e campid, sid etc coming from any html form? 
then in that form set method post. & then in php code get all parameters with $_POST...

```
$campid = $_POST['campid'];
$sid = $_POST['sid']; 
$rate = $_POST['rate'];
```